# Unable to determine correct version D3 for sample code I found

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm experimenting with the example code at: http://jsfiddle.net/7HZcR/3/
I get an error that there is no such function as force.
I tried d3.force() and d3.forceSimulation().
I looked for the error message and it seems like this is due to a version change.
I don't see in jsFiddle where the script file includes the D3 code, so I don't know what version it's using.  Is there a way to determine which version of D3 one should include?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Test of http://jsfiddle.net/7HZcR/3/ </title>
    <style>
        cut-n-paste of css code
    </style>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        cut-n-paste of js code
        blah blah
    var force = d3.layout.force()
        .nodes(d3.values(nodes))
        .links(links)
        .size([w, h])
        .linkDistance(60)
        .charge(-300)
        .on("tick", tick)
        .start();
        blah
    </script>
</head>
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="chart"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, heck. As soon as I typed the question, I tried googling "d3.layout.force()" and it returned help pages for versions 3.0 and 3.1.  Sample still doesn't work ... not sure why ... BUT no more error message.

Comment: If you click on the resources side bar of jsfiddle and then d3.js, it takes you to http://mbostock.github.io/d3/d3.js, which then inserts [version 2](http://d3js.org/d3.v2.js). This is a pretty old example!

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize that was clickable. The sample works in my Chrome browser, but this code doesn't. But at least it doesn't give me an error. Is there an option to give the entire working program rather than the user trying to figure out how to piece things together.

Comment: @elbillaf Check my answer below :)

Comment: @elbillaf, I'm not sure if there's a way to export it to one file. But you can try moving the JavaScript tag(s) to the body (the end of the body is conventional), since this JavaScript using the document.body element. Generally for these sort of HTML/JS/CSS examples, you can recreate them by putting the *CSS* in the head, the *HTML* in the body, and the *JS* at the end of the body (and any external JS resources somewhere before the JS).

Answer (score 0):

As @Steve mentioned, the example from version 2 of d3.js, which can be found under the resource sidebar under d3.js

There's actually an easier way to get the working example: **Place your cursor on the frame, right-click and select "View Frame Source".**

<sub>(If you're using other browsers, you can still view the frame source - only the name and how it displays will be a little different)</sub>

[image: right-click menu]

You would get something similar to the following - this is the code that **powers** the frame:
[image: HTML page]

Copy and paste the entire code into an HTML file, and *voila!*

**EDIT:** If you see the "page doesn't exist" in the view source HTML page, try refreshing the JSFiddle (or click "Reload Frame" on the right-click menu) and click "View Frame Source" again.

(JSFiddle only allows a very short time window to do the "View Frame Source" action, so refresh and inspect - *don't wait!*)

You should get the code as the following:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title></title>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <meta name="googlebot" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


  <script
    type="text/javascript"
    src="/js/lib/dummy.js"
    
  ></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">

      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.js"></script>

  <style id="compiled-css" type="text/css">
      path.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #666;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

marker#licensing {
  fill: green;
}

path.link.licensing {
  stroke: green;
}

path.link.resolved {
  stroke-dasharray: 0,2 1;
}

circle {
  fill: #ccc;
  stroke: #333;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  pointer-events: none;
}

text.shadow {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 3px;
  stroke-opacity: .8;
}
    /* EOS */
  </style>

  <script id="insert"></script>


    <script src="/js/stringify.js?fb85c6454dace8cae878a1cdbaa07f21be32cac6" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script>
      const customConsole = (w) => {
        const pushToConsole = (payload, type) => {
          w.parent.postMessage({
            console: {
              payload: stringify(payload),
              type:    type
            }
          }, "*")
        }

        w.onerror = (message, url, line, column) => {
          // the line needs to correspond with the editor panel
          // unfortunately this number needs to be altered every time this view is changed
          line = line - 70
          if (line < 0){
            pushToConsole(message, "error")
          } else {
            pushToConsole(`[${line}:${column}] ${message}`, "error")
          }
        }

        let console = (function(systemConsole){
          return {
            log: function(){
              let args = Array.from(arguments)
              pushToConsole(args, "log")
              systemConsole.log.apply(this, args)
            },
            info: function(){
              let args = Array.from(arguments)
              pushToConsole(args, "info")
              systemConsole.info.apply(this, args)
            },
            warn: function(){
              let args = Array.from(arguments)
              pushToConsole(args, "warn")
              systemConsole.warn.apply(this, args)
            },
            error: function(){
              let args = Array.from(arguments)
              pushToConsole(args, "error")
              systemConsole.error.apply(this, args)
            },
            system: function(arg){
              pushToConsole(arg, "system")
            },
            clear: function(){
              systemConsole.clear.apply(this, {})
            },
            time: function(){
              let args = Array.from(arguments)
              systemConsole.time.apply(this, args)
            },
            assert: function(assertion, label){
              if (!assertion){
                pushToConsole(label, "log")
              }

              let args = Array.from(arguments)
              systemConsole.assert.apply(this, args)
            }
          }
        }(window.console))

        window.console = { ...window.console, ...console }

        console.system("Running fiddle")
      }

      if (window.parent){
        customConsole(window)
      }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="chart"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[


var links = [{source: "Microsoft", target: "Amazon", type: "licensing"},
             {source: "Microsoft", target: "Amazon", type: "suit"},
             {source: "Samsung", target: "Apple", type: "suit"},
             {source: "Microsoft", target: "Amazon", type: "resolved"}];
//sort links by source, then target
links.sort(function(a,b) {
    if (a.source > b.source) {return 1;}
    else if (a.source < b.source) {return -1;}
    else {
        if (a.target > b.target) {return 1;}
        if (a.target < b.target) {return -1;}
        else {return 0;}
    }
});
//any links with duplicate source and target get an incremented 'linknum'
for (var i=0; i<links.length; i++) {
    if (i != 0 &&
        links[i].source == links[i-1].source &&
        links[i].target == links[i-1].target) {
            links[i].linknum = links[i-1].linknum + 1;
        }
    else {links[i].linknum = 1;};
};

var nodes = {};

// Compute the distinct nodes from the links.
links.forEach(function(link) {
  link.source = nodes[link.source] || (nodes[link.source] = {name: link.source});
  link.target = nodes[link.target] || (nodes[link.target] = {name: link.target});
});

var w = 600,
    h = 600;

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .nodes(d3.values(nodes))
    .links(links)
    .size([w, h])
    .linkDistance(60)
    .charge(-300)
    .on("tick", tick)
    .start();

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg:svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h);

// Per-type markers, as they don't inherit styles.
svg.append("svg:defs").selectAll("marker")
    .data(["suit", "licensing", "resolved"])
  .enter().append("svg:marker")
    .attr("id", String)
    .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
    .attr("refX", 15)
    .attr("refY", -1.5)
    .attr("markerWidth", 6)
    .attr("markerHeight", 6)
    .attr("orient", "auto")
  .append("svg:path")
    .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");

var path = svg.append("svg:g").selectAll("path")
    .data(force.links())
  .enter().append("svg:path")
    .attr("class", function(d) { return "link " + d.type; })
    .attr("marker-end", function(d) { return "url(#" + d.type + ")"; });

var circle = svg.append("svg:g").selectAll("circle")
    .data(force.nodes())
  .enter().append("svg:circle")
    .attr("r", 6)
    .call(force.drag);

var text = svg.append("svg:g").selectAll("g")
    .data(force.nodes())
  .enter().append("svg:g");

// A copy of the text with a thick white stroke for legibility.
text.append("svg:text")
    .attr("x", 8)
    .attr("y", ".31em")
    .attr("class", "shadow")
    .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

text.append("svg:text")
    .attr("x", 8)
    .attr("y", ".31em")
    .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

// Use elliptical arc path segments to doubly-encode directionality.
function tick() {
  path.attr("d", function(d) {
    var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
        dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
        dr = 75/d.linknum;  //linknum is defined above
    return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
  });

  circle.attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
  });

  text.attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
  });
}


  //]]></script>

  <script>
    // tell the embed parent frame the height of the content
    if (window.parent && window.parent.parent){
      window.parent.parent.postMessage(["resultsFrame", {
        height: document.body.getBoundingClientRect().height,
        slug: "7HZcR"
      }], "*")
    }

    // always overwrite window.name, in case users try to set it manually
    window.name = "result"
  </script>

    <script>
      let allLines = []

      window.addEventListener("message", (message) => {
        if (message.data.console){
          let insert = document.querySelector("#insert")
          allLines.push(message.data.console.payload)
          insert.innerHTML = allLines.join(";\r")

          let result = eval.call(null, message.data.console.payload)
          if (result !== undefined){
            console.log(result)
          }
        }
      })
    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: Hmm... I did that ... I got the code listing you show, but the rest of it doesn't actually do the work.

Comment: @elbillaf You mean you still cannot see the nodes? Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: The code to produce the nodes is not there.  The last bit of code is ...
      img {
        overflow: hidden;
        border-radius: 120px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="mCont">
      <h1>404</h1>

      <section>
        <p>That page doesn't exist.</p>
      </section>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>

Comment: Note that I have gotten the hand woven code to work - and I understand why it works now - but it would be convenient, if I could get this work.

Comment: @elbillaf Thanks for the follow-up. I just replicated that issue as well - try refreshing the JSFiddle(or right-click --> Reload Frame) and click "View Frame Source" again. That should solve the problem. It appears that JSFiddle refreshes the frame automatically and there's only a very short time window to view the source